# Search results filter - controller or service or filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have a search results page. The search results page is basically one large controller at the moment. I have code which is for the filters however this isn't an angularjs filter as such because I'm making another search to back-end and I'm not just returning a different array set. I want to keep the filter separete from the search results controller because its already large as it is. My question is: do I make it another controller and broadcast changes to the searchResults controller or do I make it a service or is it actually a filter?

I'm currently thinking a separete controller makes more sense as I'm still having to use scope but with a service I can only use $rootScope it seems.

Overall it would be good to know what calls for a filter and controller.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where you want to do the data filtering. If you're doing it server-side, then I'd put it in the service that you're probably already using to get the data. If you're not using a service to get the data, I'd recommend pulling that out of the controller first.

If you want to just grab all the data and then handle the filtering in the client, then you can create a filter module and pass it into the app to be called in the view. Depending on how complex your filtering is, it might be as simple as using one of Angular's built-in filters.

Hard to get more specific without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Currently it is a service however I'm having to use a lot of $rootScope which I'm not fond of. Would having a controller for the filter and a service hooked to that controller be a better way to do things?

Comment: You don't normally need to use $rootScope for a service. Usually you pass the module into the controller and use it that way. As far as the filter, it's hard to say without knowing exactly what you're filtering for and against. Angular built-in filters do a great job of narrowing down results based on values. But if you're doing more transformative stuff, you'll need custom filters.

Comment: It seems that angularjs filters are only good if you have the full result set back with everything you need to do the filtering but this isn't the case. My filter list contains a large list of filter options that basically have various hotels tagged against various facilities etc but the bulk of the work is done on the back-end for this. I'm thinking if I'm having to use a lot of $rootScope (which I am then) I should be making it a controller instead.

Comment: I'm now currently in the process of splitting up my http services that request and retrieve from back-end into a service and the rest will be in the filter controller.

I do find angularjs filters a great way to do quick filtering based on a current visible result set but at times I find it limiting especially when it comes to wanting to paginate the result set which involves separate requests to back-end and not retrieving one large bulky result set.

Comment: That's why I asked. We moved our filtering to the back-end for most stuff because of pagination. However, most of our processing even for pagination and filtering happens in the service. We do use $rootScope, but only because we're using websockets and need to $apply the changes. If we were using conventional REST API, we wouldn't need $rootScope at all.